# Youtube Live Broadcast Status always at complete

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I'm using OBS to stream my screen to Youtube Live.

While my stream is live I'm querying the `liveBroadcasts/list` endpoint to know if my broadcast is live.

`part` -> `id, status`

`mine` -> `true`

```
HTTP GET: GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts?part=id%2Cstatus&mine=true&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

The `status` dictionary returns something like this 
even if my stream is live:

```
"status": {
    "lifeCycleStatus": "complete",
    "privacyStatus": "public",
    "recordingStatus": "recording"
}
```

The value for the [`lifeCycleStatus`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts#status.lifeCycleStatus) I'm looking for is `live` but the API always returns `complete`

I don't want to use the `search.list` endpoint due to the delay.

Comment: I am not in my office, so this is preliminary: if you are looking for the status of your default live stream you need to GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts?part=contentDetails&broadcastType=persistent&mine=true 

From there you grab the boundStreamId and feed it to GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveStreams?part=status&id={YOUR boundStreamId}

Comment: The broadcastType parameter is the solution I was looking for! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Broadcast status can be queried for the specific video using below GET request:

```
GET    https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=7OyvXCM63uQ&key=API_KEY&part=liveStreamingDetails,snippet
```

Response :

```
Snippet.liveBroadcastContent: "upcoming",
liveStreamingDetails: {
scheduledStartTime: "2016-06-19T18:47:04.000Z",
scheduledEndTime: "2016-06-19T19:17:04.000Z"
}
```